# tf.session() takes very long time

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS EC2 with 16 GPU Tesla.
When I finished installing tensorflow and was tyring to see if it works it stopped.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

this works.

```
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
```

this works

```
sess = tf.Session()
```

This gives an error

```
2018-01-30 06:48:00.543428: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-30 06:48:00.545858: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:0f.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.03GiB
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two logs are just pieces of information. If you want to, you can disable them as provided in this great answer: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7778#issuecomment-281678077

Comment: Yes but is it common thing that the creation of session takes long time?

Comment: @samutamm tf.Session() takes around a 1 min for the first run on my machine. Did you find any solution for that?